# Wordpress Rewrite Rules Using Capture

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I'm trying to make a rewrite rule for d3 visualizations that I'll be keeping in my theme folder. Ultimately I want

```
    d3/[some-year]/[some-string]
```

to redirect to

```
    wp-content/themes/my-theme/d3-library/[some-year]/[some-string]/index.html
```

However, I can't get the capture rules to work. Here's what I have so far:

```
    function d3_rewrite() {
        add_rewrite_rule(
            'wp-content/themes/d3/(20[0-9][0-9]/.*)',
            'wp-content/themes/my-theme/assets/d3-library/$match[1]/index.html',
            'top'
        );
    }
    add_action('init', 'd3_rewrite');
```

Does anyone know why this doesn't work?

Comment: Did you try `'wp-content/themes/my-theme/assets/d3-library/$1/index.html',`?

Comment: If you want to post that as an answer I'll upvote it to mark this as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `wp-content/themes/my-theme/assets/d3-library/$1/index.html`. The problem is in the replacement back-reference.

Answer (score 0):

Where you have `$match[1]`, shouldn't that be `$matches[1]`?

Comment: `matches` didn't work so I also tried `match` because I saw it in a PHP regex tutorial. So it should probably be `matches` but that doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Hmm... also don't know if it's relevant but your example has it substituting `d3/[some-year]/[some-string]` but the rule is looking for `wp-content/themes/d3/[some-year]/[some-string]`

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding you, isn't that the point of having rewrite rules? So that the user can type in something pretty like `blah.com/d3/2015/graph` and be redirected to something ugly like `blah.com/wp-content/themes/d3-library/2015/graph/index.html` without ever having to see the ugly url at all.

Comment: Yes, but your rewrite rule as written requires them to enter `wp-content/themes/...` You probably want the regexp parameter to be `'d3/(20[0-9][0-9]/.*)'` instead of `'wp-content/themes/d3/(20[0-9][0-9]/.*)'`

Comment: Oh, I see what you're saying. I wasn't clear in the post--that's my ultimate goal, but I was starting with the code I provided because it greatly simplifies the possibility of the error being caused by something other than the capture. Anyway, @stribizhez's comment solved the problem!